# The derivative of a function satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2$

Tags: real-analysis

The function satisfies the following two conditions:

\begin{align*}
f(x+y)&=f(x)+f(y)+x^2y+xy^2\\
\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}&=1
\end{align*}
Find:

$i.$ $f(0)$;

$ii.$ $f'(0)$;

$iii.$ $f'(x)$.

---

This is what I have done so far, although I am not sure that it is exactly correct. For $i.$ we set $y=0$ to get
$$f(x)=f(x)+f(0)$$
which gives $f(0)=0$. This is expected since any other value would make the limit condition false, so I'm pretty sure this is correct. For $ii.$, since we know that $f(0)=0$ the limit has an indeterminate form $\dfrac{0}{0}$ and so by L'Hospital we get
$$ \lim _{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=1\rightarrow f'(0)=1 $$
but here I used the fact that $f'(x)$ is continuous at $0$ and nothing is said about the function other than the given conditions.

Now I know that $f(x)$ must be a polynomial function due to the $x^2y+xy^2$ term in the definition and more precisely it must be of the form 
$$f(x)=0+1\cdot x+\sum _{n=2}c_nx^n$$
and here $n$ must not be higher than 3 since this would produce terms $x^3y$, $x^2y^2$ etc. which would not cancel out. In fact, setting $y=-x$ with $f(0)=0$ gives $f(x)+f(-x)=0$ and thus $c_2=0$. The function can be easily found to be
$$f(x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}$$
from which we deduce that $f'(x)=1+x^2$.

My questions are these:

1) How can I justify the step 
$$\lim _{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=f'(0)$$
with no information on the continuity?

2) Is there a way to find $f'(x)$ without having to find $f(x)$?

Comment: Concerning your first question, the limit hypothesis is the definition of ii.

Comment: Can we find $f(x)$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $x=0,y=0$ to get $f(0)=0$.
Now note that 
$$\frac{f(x+y)-f(x)}{y}=\frac{f(y)}{y}+x^2+xy,\text{ for }y\not=0.$$
Let $y\to 0$ to obtain $f'(x)=x^2+1$.

Comment: Excellent! This is what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can compute $f'(x)$ using the definition of derivative: if you write
$$
f(x+h)=f(x)+f(h)+x^2h+xh^2,
$$
you obtain that
$$
f'(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} =\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(h)+x^2h+xh^2}{h} = 1+x^2,
$$
the last equality is due to
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}=1.
$$